# requests: Request never terminates on windows machine

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, request

I have the problem, that a simple GET HTTP request does not execute on an AWS EC2 Windows Server Machine with Python 3.6.3 running:

```
import requests
requests.get('http://some_picture_url')
```

The command never terminates on the windows machine. I can retrieve the image in Internet Explorer on the same machine.

How can I debug this? Other urls just work fine.

Comment: Try running requests with verbose logging.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your requirement is to fetch the image to the server. Since you can access the image via explorer, we can rule out any firewall/security groups blocking the access.

Can you try the below script in your machine

```
import shutil
import requests

url = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png'
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('1.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
del response
```

For debugging the URL, I'd suggest checking the URL response.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png')
print(r.status_code)
```